# How do I substitute a label in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to select all items on a page that have a particular label and substitute that labels value with something different.

Below is as far as I have gotten so far

```
$j("optgroup[label=Available]").
```

When the an optgroup tag has a label of Available I would like it to be something else (i.e. Options)

How do I complete this line?

Comment: Have you tried `$j("optgroup[label=Available]").attr('label', 'Options')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `attr`?

```
$("optgroup[label='Available']").attr("label", "Options");
```

You can see a fiddle in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/s58Lk/

attr documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Here is a demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/qFvas/ though I dropped the $j version of the jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the label attribute, you could try something like this:

```
$j("optgroup[label=Available]").attr('label', 'Options');
```

**A little explanation**

The `attr` read and changes the value of a attributes in a html tag:

Read the current value

```
var label = $("...").attr("label");
```

Change the value:

```
$("...").attr("label", "new value");
```